# Swift 4 - Editing label frame.size.height with negative number

Tags: ios, swift, label, size

So I have a label that I've made in Xcode's storyboard which I want to later edit in my code. I want it to simulate something like a vertical bar so I am editing its height by doing:

```
answerE.frame.size.height = -200
```

The problem comes from the negative number, I want the label to "grow" up so the height has to be negative from its original position... I have the line in code in a simple action on button press, but each time the line is executed the label moves "up" and eventually after 3-4 clicks is out of the screen.
I just want to edit its height, what is the correct way and what am I doing wrong?

My exact line in code is:

```
label.frame.size.height = -CGFloat(Double(x)/Double(y) * (200))
```

Comment: Why does it have to be negative to start with?  Could it not be zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added the label in storyboard, why not you use constraints to get the result.

Add leading, trailing , bottom and fixed height constraint and connect `IBOutlet` to height constraint. Change the constant value of height constraint at the event which you want to perform.

Comment: You are right actually, that is also a possible solution, sorry that I can only choose 1 accepted answer, your solution is also really good

Comment: This is the solution that worked as intended. The other one (using both origin and height) was giving producing problems - it didn't apply the first time I execute it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, you want the label to gain height, keeping the same bottom edge, but the top edge moving up.

In order to do this, you want to change the frame.origin.y as you change the frame.size.height at the same amount, as its placement (and so top edge) is determined by its origin. So maybe make it zero height, place it where you want it in storyboard, and then when you want it to 'grow' by x:

```
label.frame.size.height = label.frame.height + x
label.frame.origin.y = label.frame.origin.y - x
```